# cant register beacon on beacon tools

Tags: beacon, eddystone

Every time I try to register the beacon on the google beacon tools app on andriod I add the location but it does not seem to let me register it, The register beacon text is greyed out. Is there any way to register the beacon?

Comment: Which beacon are you using? I had the same problem with CC2541 from AprilBeacons. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are trying to register an Eddystone-URL (or maybe Eddystone-EID) beacon. The Beacon Tools App will only let you register iBeacon or Eddystone-UID beacons. It will detect some other types of beacon broadcasts, but only supports these two frame types. I have seen this in the Beacon Tools App, that when I detect an Eddystone-URL broadcast, I can touch on it, but "Register Beacon" is greyed out.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/beacons/get-started#2-configure-your-beacons) you can see that Google says to use Eddystone-UID (or EID, [but that setup is more complicated](https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/register#register_an_eddystone-eid_beacon)). And [here](https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/developer_faq#does_product_name_support_ibeacon) they say that iBeacon is also supported for Nearby Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

It may be you have already register that beacon to other project.
If not, then create one project on [Google API Console](https://console.developers.google.com).

And select your project on Beacon Tools App and then proceed.

Your beacon must be configured as Eddystone. otherwise Beacon Tools App will not detect.

try it

Answer (score 0):

As @David said, if you used Eddystone URL, the register option on beacon tools would be greyed out.

But only enabling Eddystone UID would not work for me either, because beacon tools would not recognize my beacon at all. What I did to make this work was to enable **both iBeacon and Eddystone UID** during configuration.

After you register your beacon on beacon tools, you need to refresh the "registered" list to see it appears there. Or go to the Google developer dashboard of your project.